# Stick 2 Image views dimensions in all iOS devices

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to thank anyone of you who is contributing to this community, and i which to find a solution to the issue that is presented below:

[this is a capture of my xcode project Main Storyboard:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHq6i.png)

it contains a background image view with a grid picture and a small image view over it with a cercle picture.the content mode is the same for both views is aspect fit.

what i am trying to achieve here is to get the same combination between the two images, as in this picture, on all devices.
so basically sticking the cercle image to the background image (the grid image) so that if the background image dimensions change on another device the dimensions of the cercle image change the same way to keep the same view as in this picture.

Comment: What about contentMode and Aspect Ratio?

Comment: content mode is the same for both views: aspect fit and aspect ratio not selected for both

Comment: Have you tried using proportional constraints? Assuming both images are "square" (equal width-to-height), constrain the circle image view width to the width of the grid image view, with a 0.1 multiplier (or whatever ratio is correct)?

Comment: the red lines close to the cercle are equal width and height constraints that i tried the multiplier for the height is 0.059 and the width 0.077

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed your image and clipped out the circle.

The "grid" actual pixels are `312 x 324`. The "circle" is `30 x 30`.

I set the grid imageView to `fill`, with a width-to-height ratio of `312:324` and a width of `0.75` to superview.

I set the circle imageView to `fill`, with a width-to-height ratio of `1:1` and a width constraint of `30:312` of the grid imageView.

Here is the result:

[image]

You would need to calculate the run-time" ratio for placement, but that's pretty straight-forward.

---

**Edit:**

I whipped up a simple example - has buttons to move the circle based on the intersection points: https://github.com/DonMag/GridScale

Comment: is it valid for other placements ? (you choosed the center of the grid)

Comment: The *sizing* is independent from the placement... I assume you're already calculating placement for one resolution? If so, just translate it to the new "run-time" resolution. e,g, if the vertical lines are 30-pts apart at "native" resolution, multiply that by `runtimeWidth / nativeWidth`. The size constraints will keep the sizes relative without any additional coding.

Comment: did you set the grid imageView to aspect fill ?

Comment: Both set to `fill`... the width-to-height ratio on the imageView eliminates the need for `aspectFill`.

Comment: please define runtimeWidth,runtime ratio,run-time" resolution,native width? what's the differenc between fill and aspect fill?

Comment: Thank you Man, i have a question abouthow you made a hole in that ring picture? it shows the grid behind in the hole of the ring

Comment: You mean the one on xcode? that affects the side of the ring too i want the hole to be affected alone. any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming you have the ring as a bitmap / .png? Just cut a hole with your image editor. If not, how are you generating the ring?